# SSI Processing Error on local IIS website, but works on other webserver

Tags: html, iis, ssi

I have a website where I'm using the SSI directive #include virtual.

```
<!--#include virtual="_includes/top_nav.html" -->
```

_includes is a folder in the root of the website on the webserver. I created a Virtual Directory on my Default Website in IIS so I could do development locally. I called it devgroupsite.

I get SSI Processing errors when running the site on my IIS site. If I do this:

```
<!--#include virtual="devgroupsite/_includes/top_nav.html" -->
```

It works, but then of course it won't work on my actual webserver.

Do you know how I can create a IIS virtual directory or new IIS website in order to be able to use the "_includes/top_nav.html"? Or am I just using IIS wrong?

Thanks in advance guys!!!

Comment: something that did work was to set my Default Web Sites path to my working folder's path of the website. Of course, this isn't the best solution... I tried adding the website as an Application but that didn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have found a solution. Rather than adding it as a virtual directory on my Default Web Site, I created a new website under Sites. Now it appears to work correctly.